# PLSQL : DBMS Jobs - parallelization?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, parallelism

I am looping over a cursor and executing a stored procedure; how do I parallelize this process through dbms.jobs?

```
for rec in select column from table1
loop
execute stored_procedure( rec.column );
end loop;
```

Comment: Would creating 2 separate threads help you?

Answer (score 1):

The pl/sql package DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE can be used to parallelize pl/sql. Examples can be found in the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm#CHDEABDB). You can use the first example (Chunk by ROWID):

define a procedure

```
create process_chunk(start_id rowid, end_id in row_id)
...
begin  
...
for rec in select column from table1 where rowid between start_id and end_id
  loop
  stored_procedure( rec.column );
  end loop;
...
end;
/
```

and then (following the example) write a job that does the following

```
...
begin
...
--create a task
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_TASK ('mytask');
-- Chunk the table by ROWID in chunks of 100 rows
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID('mytask', USER, 'TABLE1', true, 100);
-- execute with parallel level 10
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('mytask', 'call process_chunk(:start_id,:end_id)',
  DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,  parallel_level => 10);

--and implement code for error handling and removing the task according to the example.
...
end;
```